# Python regex for parsing

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

This below mentioned out put i am generating from ansible and i want to remove all play and task titles

> ```
> PLAY [enroll certificate] ******************************************************
>
> TASK [upating the task status] *************************************************
> ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
> ok: [localhost]
>     
> TASK [Iterate JSON] ************************************************************
> }
>     
> PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
> localhost  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
> ```

I am using the below code to generate the required output,  but you can see i am using multiple line of code to achieve this, can we reduce the line of code and simplify the code ?

```
    result_success2 = re.sub(r'^PLAY.*\n?', '', result_success, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    result_success3 = re.sub(r'^TASK.*\n?', '', result_success2, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    result_success4 = re.sub(r'^ok.*\n?', '', result_success3, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    result_success5 = re.sub(r'^localhost.*\n?', '', result_success4, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    result_success6 = re.sub(r'^}.*\n?', '', result_success5, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    result_success7 = re.sub(r'\n\s*\n','\n',result_success6,re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: What are the rules for which lines are to be spared?

Comment: starting with PLAY/TASK/ok/Localhost

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the results, using ansible as a library is all your need.

see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html